# Weird Segmentcontrol functionality happening

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

OK so this is what's happening. If I click on segment "0" (the right most, since segmentcontrol in ios counts 0 as to the right ) out of the 5 segments that I have, the first time it goes through the correct one, which is "0". But the second time I click on it, it thinks i clicked on segment 3?! This is VERY strange! Can someone help me out? Here is my code:

```
        if ([[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2]isSelected] )
    {
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:originalColor];

        [self removeAllTables];
        [self displayTables:[Globals sharedInstance].StartUp.Tables];
        self.tableManagement.scrollEnabled = YES;

    }else if ([[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3]isSelected] ){

        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:originalColor];

        [self removeAllTables];
        [self displayTables:[Globals sharedInstance].StartUp.Tables];

    }else if ([[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4]isSelected] ){

        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:originalColor];

        [self removeAllTables];
        [self displayTables:[Globals sharedInstance].StartUp.Tables];
        self.tableManagement.scrollEnabled = YES;

    }else if ([[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1]isSelected] ){

        self.currentTable = @"-1";
        _firstTableForCombine = @"-1";
        _nextTable = @"-1";
        _splitTable = @"-1";
        _lastsegmentIndex = -1;
        _segmentOneClicked = false;
        _segmentTwoClicked = false;
        _segmentZeroClicked = false;

        [self.SplitForm removeFromSuperview];
        [self.roundFrameForSplit removeFromSuperview];
        [self.moveOrderToA removeFromSuperview];
        [self.moveOrderToB removeFromSuperview];


        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:originalColor];

        wait((int*)1000);
        [self removeAllTables];
        [self displayTables:[Globals sharedInstance].StartUp.Tables];
        _segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.2
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector (changeToOriginalColor)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: NO];
        self.tableManagement.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }else if ([[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:0]isSelected] ){
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:originalColor];
        if(_segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && _segmentZeroClicked)
        {
            [self Normal];
        }else
        {
            [self magnify];
        }
    }
```

EDITED CODE:

```
        //This handles all the background color of the segment control when the user clicks on
    //one of the functions.
    if (_segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 )
    {
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:originalColor];

        [self removeAllTables];
        [self displayTables:[Globals sharedInstance].StartUp.Tables];
        self.tableManagement.scrollEnabled = YES;

    }else if (_segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 ){

        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:originalColor];

        [self removeAllTables];
        [self displayTables:[Globals sharedInstance].StartUp.Tables];

    }else if (_segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ){

        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:originalColor];

        [self removeAllTables];
        [self displayTables:[Globals sharedInstance].StartUp.Tables];
        self.tableManagement.scrollEnabled = YES;

    }else if (_segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex == 3){

        self.currentTable = @"-1";
        _firstTableForCombine = @"-1";
        _nextTable = @"-1";
        _splitTable = @"-1";
        _lastsegmentIndex = -1;
        _segmentOneClicked = false;
        _segmentTwoClicked = false;
        _segmentZeroClicked = false;

        [self.SplitForm removeFromSuperview];
        [self.roundFrameForSplit removeFromSuperview];
        [self.moveOrderToA removeFromSuperview];
        [self.moveOrderToB removeFromSuperview];


        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:4] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:originalColor];
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setTintColor:originalColor];

        wait((int*)1000);
        [self removeAllTables];
        [self displayTables:[Globals sharedInstance].StartUp.Tables];
        _segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.2
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector (changeToOriginalColor)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: NO];
        self.tableManagement.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }else if ([[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:0]isSelected] ){
        [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:originalColor];
        if(_segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && _segmentZeroClicked)
        {
            [self Normal];
            return;
        }else
        {
            [self magnify];
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Segment 0 is the left most segment, not the right.

Comment: It's the right most. if using _segmentControlTableFunctions.selectedSegmentIndex , then you start from left --> right, if using [[_segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:0]isSelected], you start from right --> left

Comment: I NSLog'ed the values by clicking on the segments..to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subviews are not static. I suspect that when you select a tab the view hierarchy changes (add a gloss, shift things around or other things) and the indexes are no longer what you suspect. As someone commented the selected segment index is left first. I would strongly suggest switching to using the selected segment index instead of basing it off of the index in the subviews. The values returned from the selected index will always be correct.

Comment: Yes, I found the same thing. Clicking on various segments and looking at which subview is selected, gives inconsistent results.

Comment: Ok. Now what happens is when i click on say 3rd segment, and then select segment 1 right after, segment 0 gets highlited.. WAT THE HELL>

Comment: How do i specify the segment tint color without using the subviews thing that i use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827297/uisegmented-control-setting-the-tint-color-of-each-segment

Answer (score 0):

The tintColor property is only meant to change the tint of the whole control. If you want to change the color of the selected segment vs the unselected segments, you should use setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics: instead. You will need to create one color images, if that's the look you want. It can be done like this (sc is my outlet to the segmented control):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenColor.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GrayColor.png"];
    [self.sc setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.sc setBackgroundImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

SO for those wondering, this worked for me. :)

```
                for (int i = 0; i < self.segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews.count; i++)
            {
                if ([[self.segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )
                {
                    [[self.segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
                }
                else
                {
                    [[self.segmentControlTableFunctions.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:originalColor];
                }
            }
```